# Table using dataset not rendering

Tags: jasper-reports, dataset, import-from-csv, xmltable

I am trying below *JRXML* to render data from *CSV datasource*. This *JRXML* has bar chart as well as table taking data from same *CSV datasource*. Bar chart is getting rendered without any issue, but table is not getting rendered. Please advise.

I am using *Jaspersoft Studio 5.1.0* for report development.

My *JRXML*:

```xml
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="AEReport_1" pageWidth="800" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="760" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="155eb524-de3b-4d18-98af-83ffc65bff68">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="V2_FLAT_FILE_CSV"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#B8860B">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFEDBF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#FFFAEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BD955F">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#E6DCCF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#F8F6F3"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#D2B48C">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFE4BF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 4_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#FFF8EF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BD955F">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#E6DCCF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 5_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#F8F6F3"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#FBFDFF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 3_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#DEB887">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 3_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFE3BF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table 3_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean($V{REPORT_COUNT}.intValue()%2==0)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#F6EDE1"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1" uuid="3e8114ed-92a8-4069-89a5-fbdb253c6ce9"/>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset A" uuid="2e726566-2d24-49ba-84bb-5994c8f9d50b">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="V2_FLAT_FILE_CSV"/>
        <parameter name="dateFrom" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="dateTo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString language="csv">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="COUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <field name="ANLYS_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="APP_MNEMONIC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset B" uuid="9b3ebb93-6694-430d-80fe-625fdfaae930">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="V2_FLAT_FILE_CSV"/>
        <parameter name="dateFrom" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="dateTo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString language="csv">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="COUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <field name="ANLYS_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="APP_MNEMONIC" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <group name="APP_MNEMONIC">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{APP_MNEMONIC}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
        <group name="ANLYS_DATE">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ANLYS_DATE}]]></groupExpression>
        </group>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="dateFrom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dateTo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="reportUser" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString language="csv">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="COUNT" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="ANLYS_DATE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="APP_MNEMONIC" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement uuid="667e0ea3-a911-4d00-8067-2e89b3780fda" x="0" y="0" width="136" height="54"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\ADCXDPF\\Desktop\\bnymellon.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement uuid="7a842faa-9b66-489a-90ad-5375cd1272de" x="230" y="30" width="253" height="33"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="16" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Throughput Summary Report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="d119d0a9-8b20-4a5e-aee6-e16cee9b228c" x="100" y="43" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateFrom}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="c931fbfb-d41d-4890-979d-570cdd1d3d49" x="0" y="4" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Report Parameters]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="496c107b-9e9f-4e50-8cf4-0d158c2d3c1d" x="100" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportUser}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="f89feee2-3b9d-43cf-b738-386b96dd005c" x="0" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[User            :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="56beec91-5509-4cdb-8155-54dfae54296f" x="0" y="43" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date From  :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="a0cc21e8-1610-4f72-b729-f90648762326" x="0" y="63" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Date To      : ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="b9df36a8-4fac-4eb4-91a2-970179703202" x="100" y="63" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{dateTo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="549" splitType="Stretch">
            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT} == 1]]></printWhenExpression>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="64346d62-eee3-493a-b044-39c4b06419d4" x="-18" y="257" width="778" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="51143f56-11c9-4c86-adaf-6a9567e55dcd" x="-18" y="4" width="778" height="3"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="d649fb76-7f5b-4777-ba74-eec842bc3620" x="200" y="7" width="159" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Activity Summary By Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <barChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="false" evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement uuid="21819f57-e2b0-4d97-b0c3-212eaeb45b81" x="-1" y="37" width="521" height="208"/>
                    <chartTitle>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA[]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{ANLYS_DATE}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{ANLYS_DATE}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowTickMarks="false">
                    <plot>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#B08057"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#8599A8"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#94996E"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="3" color="#667D78"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="4" color="#8F6678"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="5" color="#A3A19E"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Processing Date"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont>
                                <font isBold="true"/>
                            </labelFont>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Total Hit"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont>
                                <font isBold="true"/>
                            </labelFont>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
            <lineChart>
                <chart isShowLegend="true">
                    <reportElement uuid="41772b49-87de-4350-9ad0-00a78f5246d0" x="1" y="288" width="459" height="207"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{APP_MNEMONIC}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{ANLYS_DATE}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <linePlot>
                    <plot>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#B08057"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#8599A8"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#94996E"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="3" color="#667D78"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="4" color="#8F6678"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="5" color="#A3A19E"/>
                    </plot>
                    <categoryAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Processing Date"]]></categoryAxisLabelExpression>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont>
                                <font isBold="true"/>
                            </labelFont>
                            <tickLabelFont>
                                <font isBold="true"/>
                            </tickLabelFont>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisLabelExpression><![CDATA["Total Hit"]]></valueAxisLabelExpression>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat>
                            <labelFont>
                                <font isBold="true"/>
                            </labelFont>
                        </axisFormat>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </linePlot>
            </lineChart>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="72fb52e9-7c93-40bc-a6eb-3adcf0f5c10f" x="200" y="260" width="193" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Activity Summary By Application]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement uuid="6bd73234-2b4b-4f40-a95b-43b0f04a041e" x="540" y="20" width="200" height="160" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset A" uuid="4ca25032-c8da-46c0-a75f-0ad3f60b0571">
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="fbb13626-5aad-4322-ba9e-80cdfe4a55e8">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table 3_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table 3_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table 3_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="403cc6c2-c57e-4741-840d-57c1269a7551" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <text><![CDATA[ANLYS_DATE]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table 3_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="c80f6de6-0114-482b-91d2-d0ffee0c5481" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ANLYS_DATE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="07468b4f-03a5-4f62-97c8-a0489c687664">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table 3_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table 3_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table 3_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="3e081981-714d-434b-b7eb-2a0109559506" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <text><![CDATA[COUNT]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table 3_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table 3_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement uuid="0fba778b-3de3-49fb-8176-97ff6d73a785" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
                                <textElement/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="e8424fab-a95e-4c89-8af0-a0d12a89ff1b" x="1" y="9" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[Run Date :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="2abd8771-abef-4722-8526-69abf4e81630" x="633" y="9" width="80" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement uuid="a1bb581a-8214-4074-be04-5493e100c787" x="713" y="9" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss">
                <reportElement uuid="dbacf251-c81f-4e05-82ab-029d82139e0b" x="51" y="9" width="164" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

CSV data is:

```
"COUNT","ANLYS_DATE","APP_MNEMONIC"
9932,"2013-08-27","ESD"
1132,"2013-08-26","ESD"
2532,"2013-08-25","ESD"
902,"2013-08-27","JMETER"
920,"2013-08-26","JMETER"
1120,"2013-08-25","JMETER"
1109,"2013-08-27","LND"
2229,"2013-08-26","LND"
9999,"2013-08-25","LND"
11646,"2013-08-24","SPU"
1646,"2013-08-26","SPU"
111646,"2013-08-27","SPU"
```

Comment: How did you check your report? With help of *iReport* or with *Java* code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try  this
You need a subdatset for the Table
Right click on the Table .Edit table datasource.
 Choose the datasource you need. In the connection/Datasource Expression
Choose -->"Use datasource Expression"
Use the following in the expression

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRCsvDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE})
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks that renders the table.

Comment: @cjava what if my table is contained with in a list element?

Comment: I had the same issue and I solved usign REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP. In jaspersoft studio the reports works fine. By the way if I call the report from a java program table are not printed! Why is that? Does anyone could help me please?